# Java compilation error "cannot find symbol" method getFiles(String)

Tags: java, spring

In rebuilding a jointly-developed J2EE application, I'm getting the following compilation error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
List<MultipartFile> mpFileList = request.getFiles (fileParm);
symbol:   method getFiles(String)
location: variable request of type MultipartHttpServletRequest
```

The class **MultipartHttpServletRequest** extends both **HttpServletRequest** and **MultipartRequest**, and the method in question (i.e., `getFiles(String)`) is one of the methods of the **MultipartRequest** class, which is located in the package `org.springframework.web.multipart` I've included in my NetBeans project by adding the JAR `spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar`. Why is Netbeans saying it can't find the method when it exists in one of the project JAR files?

Comment: Is the `jar` on the project `buildpath`?

Comment: also double check your imports

Comment: @brso05: I can see it in my list of compile-time libraries in NetBeans...

Comment: @RC: I just took out the import statement to have the compiler prompt me for it, then I put in the suggested imports and recompiled, but it didn't make a difference...

Comment: It may be there for `compile time` but is it there for `runtime`? Is it in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder?

Comment: @brso05: I see the JAR file in the WEB-INF/lib folder in the build directory, and if I look in the last WAR file I built, it's there as well. If I switch to an older version of the file that uses getFile(String) instead of getFiles(String), that works just fine, and both methods are in the same class, so I'm not sure why it finds one and not the other...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that every compile problem is different, but I wanted to post the solution to my problem in case it helps someone else debug their issue. The closest person to the "answer" was @brso05, with his suggestion about checking for the JAR in question being present in the WEB-INF/lib. That got me wondering what would happen if I extracted the relevant object classes from the JAR in the `WEB-INF\classes` folder.

Sure enough, that worked, which made me wonder if the JARs included in my project had more than one version of the class in question (i.e., maybe a version without the method needed was being found before the one with the method) So I removed all the Spring JARs from my project properties and just added the one I needed (**spring-webXXX.jar**) and any others based on any additional compile/runtime complaints of the compiler. I'm now able to compile and run without issue.

While I can't say exactly which JAR or library was the guilty party, at least I figured out the right approach to solving the problem. Thanks for all of your suggestions...

Comment: In doing some further checking on my compilation process this morning, I pinpointed the JAR in question that I need to have my Spring jar be listed ahead of. It's a JAR compiled in another project, so perhaps that project has an older version of the MultiPartRequest that's missing the method I need, and I may be able to update the JARs I use in that project to eliminate this issue altogether...

Comment: I just confirmed that for the version of Spring I've been using to build my subordinate project, the class **MultipartHttpServletRequest** does not contain the method in question, hence the compilation error whenever that project's JAR appeared before my more up-to-date Spring jar...